# The rails_admin gem breaks with the enum attributes introduced in Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, enums, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Rails 4.1 introduced **[enums](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2014/4/8/Rails-4-1/)**, which break **rails_admin**. Any solutions or work arounds?

My model includes the following line at the top

```
enum category: {industry: 1, company: 2, event: 3}
```

My Gemfile has the following line

```
gem 'rails_admin', :git => 'git://github.com/sferik/rails_admin.git'
```

There is no other code related to this issue. I have not modified the default behavior of the rails_admin engine. Below are the errors I am getting when trying to edit any model that contains an enum attribute through the rails_admin interface.

```
ArgumentError - '3' is not a valid category:
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/enum.rb:103:in `block (3 levels) in enum'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:45:in `_assign_attribute'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:32:in `block in assign_attributes'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:26:in `assign_attributes'
   () Users/nicolas/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails_admin-1d604b22d24c/lib/rails_admin/adapters/active_record/abstract_object.rb:19:in `set_attributes'
   () Users/nicolas/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails_admin-1d604b22d24c/lib/rails_admin/config/actions/edit.rb:29:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Edit>'
  (eval):8:in `edit'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  [...]
```

What happens is that rails_admin does not recognize enums and in its interface it displays them as numbers instead of strings. Then, when you click save, it throws the above exception.

Comment: Add around code please. So you are trying to set enam with integer and it throws that error? Maybe try to use names instead of id's if it's form select.

Comment: I am using the rails_admin engine out of the box at this point. The only relevant code is its inclusion in the Gemfile. I updated the question to include it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### This is an open issue of rails_admin.

See here: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1993

#### Summary:

add the following gist to your config/initializers
https://gist.github.com/dmilisic/38fcd407044ace7514df

Answer (score 0):

Please use [enum4](https://github.com/sibext/rails_admin_enum4) plugin for view native enum from Rails 4.1